# When should I use Tensorflow variables and when numpy or python variables

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am new to Tensorflow2.0 and try to get familiar with the library. 
I worked a lot with numpy and noticed that numpy and tensorflow variables are 'compatible'. But if I use a numpy variable or object within tensorflow, does it require tf to convert this variable to a tensor each time? If working with Tensorflow should I just initialize everything as a Tf variable or should I decide based on whether it will be used by numpy or tf? It seems that a lot of mathematical operations are also implemented in tf.math, should I ditch the numpy operations all together? 
By the way, I won't use Tensorflow for Machine Learning but mainly Tensorflow Probability for sampling etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are three kinds of variables in Tensorflow.

- `var = tf.placeholder()` defines a placeholder which is used to receive and feed raining data.
- `var = tf.constant()` creates a constant tensor.
- `var = tf.variable()` defines a variable that is trainable. Tensorflow will automatically differentiate over this kind of variable. For example, the weights and biases of a neural network should be defined using `tf.variable()`.

Numpy variable is often used to initialize both `var = tf.constant()` and `var = tf.variable()`. `var = tf.placeholder()` doesn't need to be initialized.

By the way, here is a [simple tutorial](https://github.com/suzyi/TensorFlow-Examples) which contains some hands-on examples and may help you get familiar with Tensorflow as quickｌｙ as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much! And what about Tensorflow probability? I will probably use Tensorflow rather for Monte Carlo simulations than for Machine Learning purposes. Would I even need tf.variable() or would I stick to tf.constants then?